# Generating text from a Markov chain in Java

Tags: java, random, markov-chain

I have this small program that constructs a Markov chain from Tolstoy's War and Peace and allows the user to play with it by generating sentences of variable length in words.

**MarkovChain.java**

```
package net.coderodde.markovapp;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public final class MarkovChain {

    /**
     * Number of words per state.
     */
    private final int k;

    /**
     * The array of words.
     */
    private final String[] words;

    /**
     * State transition function. 
     */
    private final Map<List<String>, Map<List<String>, Integer>> map = 
            new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Maps to each state the number of its following states.
     */
    private final Map<List<String>, Integer> totalCountMap = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * The list of all states.
     */
    private final List<List<String>> vocabulary = new ArrayList<>();

    private final Random random;

    public MarkovChain(String[] words, int k, Random random) {
        this.words = Objects.requireNonNull(words, "Word array is null.");
        this.k = checkPositive(k);

        if (words.length < k) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("number of words < k");
        }

        this.random = Objects.requireNonNull(random, "The random is null.");
        build();
    }

    public MarkovChain(String[] words, int k) {
        this(words, k, new Random());
    }

    public String[] compose(int numberOfWords) {
        checkRequestedNumberOfWords(numberOfWords);
        List<String> startState = 
                vocabulary.get(random.nextInt(vocabulary.size()));

        String[] outputWords = new String[numberOfWords];
        numberOfWords -= k;

        for (int i = 0; i < startState.size(); ++i) {
            outputWords[i] = startState.get(i);
        }

        int index = k;

        while (numberOfWords-- > 0) {
            List<String> nextState = randomTransition(startState);
            outputWords[index++] = lastOf(nextState);
            startState = nextState;
        }

        return outputWords;
    }

    private static <T> T lastOf(List<T> list) {
        return list.get(list.size() - 1);
    }

    private List<String> randomTransition(List<String> startState) {
        Map<List<String>, Integer> localMap = map.get(startState);

        if (localMap == null) {
            return vocabulary.get(random.nextInt(vocabulary.size()));
        }

        int choices = totalCountMap.get(startState);
        int coin = random.nextInt(choices);

        for (Map.Entry<List<String>, Integer> entry : localMap.entrySet()) {
            if (coin < entry.getValue()) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }

            coin -= entry.getValue();
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException("Should not get here");
    }

    private void build() {
        Set<List<String>> filter = new HashSet<>();
        Deque<String> wordDeque = new ArrayDeque<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
            wordDeque.addLast(words[i]);
        }

        for (int i = k; i < words.length; ++i) {
            List<String> startSentence = new ArrayList<>(wordDeque);
            filter.add(startSentence);

            wordDeque.removeFirst();
            wordDeque.addLast(words[i]);
            List<String> nextSentence = new ArrayList<>(wordDeque);

            Map<List<String>, Integer> localMap = map.get(startSentence);

            if (localMap == null) {
                map.put(startSentence, localMap = new HashMap<>());
            }

            localMap.put(nextSentence,
                         localMap.getOrDefault(nextSentence, 0) + 1);

            totalCountMap.put(startSentence, 
                              totalCountMap.getOrDefault(startSentence, 0) + 1);
        }

        vocabulary.addAll(filter);
    }

    private int checkPositive(int k) {
        if (k < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("k < 1");
        }

        return k;
    }

    private void checkRequestedNumberOfWords(int numberOfWords) {
        if (numberOfWords < k) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The minimum number of words for composition should be " +
                    k + ". Received " + numberOfWords);
        }
    }
}
```

**TextFileDownloader.java**

```
package net.coderodde.markovapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public final class TextFileDownloader {

    private final String urlText;

    public TextFileDownloader(String urlText) {
        this.urlText = Objects.requireNonNull(urlText, "The URL text is null.");
    }

    public String download() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlText);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                sb.append(scanner.nextLine());
            }

            return sb.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Bad URL", ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("IO failed", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**App.java**

```
package net.coderodde.markovapp;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    private static final int WORDS_PER_STATE = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        TextFileDownloader fileDownloader = 
                new TextFileDownloader(
                        "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2600/2600-0.txt");

        String text = fileDownloader.download();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        outputWithDuration("Downloaded War and Peace in ", start, end);

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String[] words = text.split("(\\s|\\W)+");
        setWordsToLowerCase(words);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        outputWithDuration("Text preprocessing took ", start, end);

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MarkovChain mc = new MarkovChain(words, WORDS_PER_STATE);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        outputWithDuration("Building Markov chain took ", start, end);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("> ");

        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            int sentenceLengthInWords = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println(concat(mc.compose(sentenceLengthInWords)));
            System.out.print("> ");
        }
    }

    private static void outputWithDuration(String text, long start, long end) {
        System.out.println(text + (end - start) + " milliseconds.");
    }

    private static String concat(String... strings) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String separator = "";

        for (String string : strings) {
            sb.append(separator);
            separator = " ";
            sb.append(string);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static void setWordsToLowerCase(String[] words) {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
            words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();
        }
    }
}
```

**Critique request**

Please tell me anything that comes to mind. Also, I believe that splitting the text into words can be improved since some words end up "glueed": `heis`, `goingto`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `concat` method can be simplified with JDK 8:

```
private static String concat(String... strings) {
    return String.join(" ", strings);
}
```

And you never close your `Scanner` in `TextFileDownloader`.

Your "glueed" words do not come from incorrect splitting but from non-optimal processing in `TextFileDownloader`: Whenever a line does not end with a space, you are glueing together the last word from the current line with the first word of the next.

A better (still not perfect) approach could be to first read all separate lines and join them together afterwards:

```
public String download() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlText);
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))) {
            return reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("IO failed", ex);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Bad URL", ex);
    }
}
```

This also makes use of JDK 7's new [`try-with-resources` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which makes dealing with resources much less cumbersome.